How to modify build.xml to provide location of jars which I otherwise provide in classpath while running the build.xml in eclipse
I have a java application which gets build as an ear using the build.xml file. Recently we are switching from Weblogic8.x to Weblogic14c, where we are facing some warnings like the following for few classes;

[wlcompile] [JAM] Warning: failed to resolve class

For resolving this, I tried adding the jar's containing these classes in the classpath  while running the of the build.xml as external tool configurations. Now I want to eliminate this and want my build.xml to refer to a folder which contains these jars, and use them while preparing the ear.
We are getting these warnings in the <taskdef name="wlcompile".
I tried giving the path of the folder containing the jars as the following;
<taskdef name="wlcompile"
in the <property name="librarydir". But still it is not able to locate the jars and the warning appear
